# openSUSE: Switch from Wicked to NetworkManager using command line

Tags: opensuse, networkmanager, suse, yast

I want to always use NetworkManager instead of Wicked.
Can I do this from the command line?

Running `sudo yast lan help` shows that the YaST lan module doesn't appear to support this from the command line.

I'm hoping whatever YaST is doing behind the scenes, I can replicate in bash.
I'm on openSUSE 13.2.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wicked; however, you should be able to switch from the command line. One of the first options in `yast lan` is to say if you want to use ifup or network manager. It's a little tui; however, from what it sounds like `networkmanager(8)` should be your best bet.

Answer (score 4):

You want to disable wicked for the next boot. This also disables related services.

```
systemctl disable wicked
```

You want to get NetworkManager started at boot time.

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager
```

The best way is to restart the system now so that you see whether the boot sequence works as expected. You may try to start/stop the services if you want to continue working and reboot and check later.

More details can be learned by examining the [service files](https://github.com/openSUSE/wicked/tree/master/etc/systemd).

Answer (score 3):

Why would you need that? 
I would recommend to mask the wicked service and rely on NetworkManager:

```
systemctl mask wicked
systemctl mask wickedd
```

Then, enable NetworkManager

```
systemctl start NetworkManager
```

Comment: wicked slow as hell